# node-mssql insert returning undefined recordset

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

Select statements are working fine, but whenever I try an insert or update the recordset and affected values are undefined.  The insert/update works in the DB, I just can't read the returned values.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {...};

sql.connect(config).then(function() {
  new sql.Request().query("INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) VALUES ('John', 30)").then(function(recordset, affected) {
    console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
    console.log('Affected: ' + affected);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Request error: ' + err);
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
  }
});
```

The output to console is:

```
Recordset: undefined
Affected: undefined
```

I feel like I must be missing something really simple here.

Comment: I know nothing of js, but: an `INSERT` statement does not return a recordset. Maybe that sheds some light on your issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the OUTPUT clause to your INSERT command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `INSERT` statement doesn't return a recordset so `recordset` is undefined. Please see [this section](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#affected-rows) of the docs to learn more about how to get number of affected rows.

The problem with your code is you're expecting `affected` as a second argument from the promise, but promises does only support one argument. Because of that you must access number of affected rows this way:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {...};

sql.connect(config).then(function() {
  var request = new sql.Request();
  request.query("INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) VALUES ('John', 30)").then(function(recordset) {
    console.log('Recordset: ' + recordset);
    console.log('Affected: ' + request.rowsAffected);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Request error: ' + err);
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('SQL Connection Error: ' + err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That makes sense, but I guess what I'm ultimately after is the value of the ID column from the newly inserted row.  What's the best way to get that?

Comment: Change your TSQL command to: `INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age) VALUES ('John', 30);SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID`

Comment: Possibly better to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` rather than `@@IDENTITY`. Would `@@IDENTITY` run into race conditions if there were many `INSERT INTO`'s happening at the same time..?

Answer (score 1):

If you want id to be output parameter

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);`
const poolConnect = pool.connect();    
let query = `INSERT INTO <table>(fields) VALUES(values);SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`
await poolConnect;
pool.request()
    .output("id", sql.Int)
    .query(query).then((err, result) => {
        console.log(result.output.id)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })`
```