# Node mssql: return id after SQL insertion

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, package

I am working on an integration between Mongodb and SQL Server, inserting and updating registers from MongoDb to SQL Server database with a scheduled process, using the `mssql` package to achieve this.

Each time a new register is inserted, I want the new row id to be retrieved back, because I need it to perform another insertions of subregisters.

I tried the following, expecting to have some information retrieved in the result of the query. The query actually inserts the row, but `result` is returned as `undefined`:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var connectionConfig = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var insertionQuery =   'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

sql.connect(connectionConfig).then(pool => {
    pool
      .request()
      .query(insertionQuery);    

}).then(result => {
        //I expect 'result' to have information of the inserted row, but it comes undefined instead
        cosole.log(result);

}).catch(err => {
        console.err(err);
});
```

I think using stored procedures may work around this, but I just want to avoid using a stored procedure for simple inserts.

Does anyone knows how to have the new row id back after insertion?

**EDIT**

I did include `OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in my SQL statement - my query now looks like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (columns...) 
OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
VALUES (values...)
```

If I run the query in my SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine and I got my new row id returned, but when running the query through the `mssql` package's `query` method, `result` is returned like this:

```
[ { '': null } ]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I quote from [node-mssql insert returning undefined recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615684/node-mssql-insert-returning-undefined-recordset):

> `INSERT` statement doesn't return a recordset so `recordset` is
>   undefined. Please see [this section](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#affected-rows) of the docs to learn more
>   about how to get number of affected rows.

An option to solve this is to add a `SELECT` statement after your `INSERT` and ask for `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `@@IDENTITY`. That will get you the ID of the last inserted objects, i.e.:`INSERT INTO table (...) VALUES (...); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;`

Comment: Thanks Francisco, that is what I'm doing now, I'm querying `INSERT INTO TABLE (columns...) OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY() VALUES (values...)`, but now I am getting `[ { '': null } ]` as the `result` of my operation. (See post edition)

Comment: As you said, correct querry was `INSERT INTO TABLE (columns...)  VALUES (values...) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id`, having for `result`  `[ { 'id': 12345} ]` Thanks again!

Comment: you should use an `OUTPUT` clause instead of a second `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes having problems with GUID, since you cannot set it as an Identity column, you must do something like:

```
const result = await pool
    .request()
    .input('orgName', sql.VarChar, orgName)
    .input('tier', sql.Int, tier)
    .input('status', sql.Int, status)
    .input('createDate', sql.Date, new Date())
    .input('statusChangeDate', sql.Date, new Date())
    .query(`INSERT INTO app.Organizations (OrgName, 
Tier, Status, CreateDate, StatusChangeDate)
 OUTPUT inserted.OrgID
 VALUES (@orgName, @tier, @status, @createDate, @statusChangeDate);
`)
```

Where the orgID is the auto generated GUID. Also don't follow my new Date() example as it inserts the date as tomorrow... I need to fix that.